# Android Download manager is delayed and always unsuccessfull

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager

So, I'm trying to implement a download pdf feature for my app. Here is the code where i start the download manager.

```
val document = documents[i]
val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("https://repository.bsi.ac.id/repo/files/256149/download/File_8-Bab-I-Pengenalan-Android.pdf"))
  .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
  .setTitle("Downloading Pdf-Android")
  .setMimeType("application/pdf")
  .setDescription("File Description")
  .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
  .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                    "Pdf-Android.pdf"
                )

val filter = IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)
applicationContext.registerReceiver(DownloadReceiver(), filter)
downloadManager.enqueue(request)
```

After quite some times, the download launch but failed immediately, and i can't really debug it since the logcat doesn't display anything. I have tried to set the allowed network types into celluar, give the permission for writing external files.

I tried to use the method from the answer, but for some reason i don't get any information in logcat. But the download still unsuccessfull and no log is found on logcat

i already register the broadcast receiver on manifset like this

```
<receiver
  android:name="somename.DownloadReceiver"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: `document.pdfUrl))` We have no idea what value that would be. Start with a good -fake- url.

Comment: `"${document.pdfName}.pdf"` same.

Comment: You do not have to set a network type.

Comment: Did you check the pdf URL? Is it working fine on the browser?

Comment: I tested the URL on my browser and even query it using software like FreeDownloadManager. And the url works just fine. Let me edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of an inconvenient situation; however, due to this code, we encounter the `DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED` error (Reason log is *Download failed: 1*). I discovered the relevant information from this link: [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager#PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY). Despite encountering this error, the documentation pertaining to it is also quite inadequate.
I just added a method like this to detect the cause of the problem.

```
val downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request)
lifecycleScope.launch {
    while (true) {
        checkDownloadStatus(applicationContext, downloadId)
        delay(10000)
    }
}


private fun checkDownloadStatus(context: Context?, downloadId: Long) {
    val downloadManager = context?.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    val query = DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId)
    val cursor = downloadManager.query(query)

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.i("DownloadManager", "cursorStarted")
        try {
            val columnStatusIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)
            val columnReasonIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON)

            val status = cursor.getInt(columnStatusIndex)

            Log.i("DownloadManagerStatus", "$status")

            when (status) {
                DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL -> {
                    Log.i("DownloadManagerSuccess", "Download successful")
                }
                DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED -> {
                    val reason = cursor.getInt(columnReasonIndex)
                    Log.e("DownloadManagerFailed", "Download failed: $reason")
                }
                DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED -> {
                    val reason = cursor.getInt(columnReasonIndex)
                    Log.e("DownloadManagerPaused", "Download paused: $reason")
                }

                else -> {
                    val reason = cursor.getInt(columnReasonIndex)
                    Log.e("DownloadManagerUnknown", "unknown : $reason")
                }
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    cursor.close()
}
```

Comment: i tried this code but still doesn't get any log

Comment: edited. please check

Comment: i tried your newest solution on using broadcast receiver. And also register the broadcast receiver on manifset, but still have no effect. Download still failing and no log to be found on logcat. Thank you

Comment: I added an example where I was able to capture the problem. But unfortunately I can't find an explanatory reason. Documents are insufficient on this subject. I think it's just about this link. I had no problems when I tried other links.

Comment: The code works, but for some links it doesn't, even when the same link can be used on something like fdm and similar app. Not really sure why, so thanks for the help. 